# Como Realizar una función de form1 al cliequear un botón en form2 .NET C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el **formulario 1** donde tengo creada una función "MostraTablaOperarias" que muestra un datagridview en el formulario 1, pues necesito que al cliquear un botón en el **formulario 2** se accione la función "MostrarTablaOperarias" del **formulario 1**.

**CÓDIGO 
FUNCION MostrarTablaOperarias (FORM1)**

```
public  void MostrarTablaOperarias()
    {

            conexion = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            //Dataset normal
            dataSet2 = new DataSet();
            //DataAdapter normal
            dataSet3 = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
            //DataAadapter Gridview
            dataAdapter3 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
            conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:/Users/David/Desktop/RP NETEJANET/BD/BDNETEJANET.accdb";

            conexion.Open();
            string sqlAdmin = "SELECT * From Operarias";


            dataAdapter2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlAdmin, conexion);
            dataAdapter2.Fill(dataSet2, "Operarias");





            dataAdapter3 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlAdmin, conexion);
            dataAdapter3.Fill(dataSet3, "Operarias");

            DataTable TablaOperarias = new DataTable();

            dataAdapter3.Fill(TablaOperarias);
            dgvO.DataSource = TablaOperarias;



            DataGridViewColumn column1 = dgvO.Columns[1];
            column1.Width = 220;

            DataGridViewColumn column2 = dgvO.Columns[2];
            column2.Width = 140;

            DataGridViewColumn column3 = dgvO.Columns[3];
            column3.Width = 100;

            DataGridViewColumn column4 = dgvO.Columns[4];
            column4.Width = 100;

            DataGridViewColumn column5 = dgvO.Columns[5];
            column5.Width = 100;

            DataGridViewColumn column6 = dgvO.Columns[6];
            column6.Width = 230;

            DataGridViewColumn column7 = dgvO.Columns[7];
            column7.Width = 150;

            DataGridViewColumn column8 = dgvO.Columns[8];
            column8.Width = 170;


            DataGridViewColumn column10 = dgvO.Columns[10];
            column10.Width = 80;








            maxRegistrosO = dataSet2.Tables["Operarias"].Rows.Count;


            conexion.Close();





            MessageBox.Show("prueba");

    }
```

**BOTÓN MostrarTablaOperarias (FORM2)**

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        MostrarTablaOperarias();
    }
```

PD: Esto lo necesito para poder refrescar el datagridview en el formulario 1 despues de insertar datos en el formulario 2.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tene en cuenta que esto no es un foro comun, aca son solo preguntas y respuestas. Pasate por los enlaces que te indique mas arriba. Y luego de eso, tu Form2, tiene una referencia al Form1?? porque de ser asi, solo tenes que hacer Form1.funcionALlamar

Comment: He estado indagando algo de instanciar el formulario 2 con el formulario 1 de manera gráfica con visual studio con el fin de poder usar funciones de otro formulario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Formulario 1** es una clase, por lo tanto necesitas tener una referencia al **Formulario 1** que sea accesible desde el **formulario 2** para poder utilizar algunos de sus métodos públicos.

Puedes pensar en pasar esa referencia desde el **formulario 1** al **formulario 2**. Puedes implementarlo, por ejemplo, agregando un constructor al **formulario 2** donde pases la referencia del **formulario 1** de la siguiente forma:

```
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 formulario2 = new Form2(this);
        }

        public void MostrarTablaOperarias()
        {
            //tareas para actualizar datagrid
        }


    }
```

**Impotente:** el puntero *this* hace referencia a la clase en la que se está trabajando, en el código anterior debería ser el **fromulario 1**.

Luego, desde el **formulario 2**, puedes utilizar cualquier método público del **formulario 1** desde la referencia que pasaste. En tu caso utilizarías el método **MostrarTablaOperarias()** :

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 fomularioAActualizar;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Form1 formulario)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fomularioAActualizar = formulario;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fomularioAActualizar.MostrarTablaOperarias();
        }
    }
```

Nota: Ten en cuenta que agregué un nuevo constructor que recibe como parámetro una referencia a una clase de tipo **formulario 1**. Deberías hacerlo para que el código funcione.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta!!!! Bienvenido y gracias por el aporte. Solo como referencia, podrias chequear [answer] y de paso hacer el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos?

Comment: No consigo que funcione de tu manera lo he hecho excatamente igual, el error que me ha dado es el siguiente : sobre el punto  "fomularioAActualizar.MostrarTablaOperarias();" System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Comment: System.NullReferenceException es el error que te tira el compilador cuando intentas acceder a una clase que no fué instanciada. Seguramente, no pasaste el puntero this en el formulario 1, es decir, no pasaste la instancia del formulario 1 al formulario 2. 
Te recomiendo poner un punto de interrupción en tu código justo en la linea donde construyes el formulario dos y verás que no pasas de forma correcta la referencia porque habrá, seguramente, un valor null.